# Having issue to load multiple tabs and/or their views in mobile web app

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am making a mobile app using sencha touch. What this app does it when user is logged in then he/she sees home view. On this `home view` there are two buttons. These two buttons takes user to their respective views i.e. `Appointments` and `Messages`. These two views have three tabs button at the bottom i.e. `Home, Appointments, Messages`. Home button takes user back to the `home view` which consists of two buttons. Whereas `Appointments` and `Messages` buttons takes him to their own views.

Here is my `home view`

[image]

As you can see there are no tabs in this view. Following is the code for this view

```
config: {
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Home',
            docked: 'top'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            cls: 'messagesBtn',
            itemId: 'msg'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            cls: 'appointmentsBtn',
            itemId: 'appoint'
        }
    ],

    listeners: [
        {
            delegate: '#appoint',
            event: 'tap',
            fn: 'launchAppointmentView'
        }
    ]
},
launchAppointmentView: function () {
    this.fireEvent('launchAppointments');
}
```

Once user clicks on lets say `Button 2` which take him to `Appointments View`. Then following is view is shown to him

[image]

and the code for this view below

```
config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Appointments',
            iconCls: 'home',

            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable: true,

            items: {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Appointments'
            },

            html: ["Appointments View"].join("")
        }
    ]
}
```

Once this view is loaded then all I can see is only one tab for Appointments. I want to see three tabs for this all three views. **How can I make other tabs visible?**

Following is my messages view

[image]

Here is the code for it

```
config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Messages',
            iconCls: 'home',

            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable: true,

            items: {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Messages'
            },

            html: ["Messages View"].join("")
        }
    ]
}
```

I cannot see this view and cannot get to this view at all because I do not have messages button on the tab. **Again how can I add all the tabs button for these views and when I click each of them so it will take me to its view?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a tab panel:

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'home',
            html: 'Home Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        }
    ]
});
```

The issue is, you haven't added addition items to you items list - they have to tabs, Home and Contact. You want 3 tabs per screen, so you would have 3 items per file.

For events, I like to create a controller, have refs for each item you need to listen for events on, and set up controls for each. Let me know if you'd like help working through how to do that. I'll include a simple example below to get you started:

```
Ext.define('Analytics.controller.events.InstType', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',   

    config: { 
        refs: {
            instType: {
            selector: '#instType'
        }
    }
},

init: function() {
    // Start listening for toggle events on the 3 segmented button panels   
    this.control({   
        'instType': { 'toggle': function(container, button, pressed) {
                this.onGraphType(container, button, pressed);
            }
        }
    }); 
},

// note: these functions are called on both the buttons selected and the one that became unselected
// the 'pressed' param inidicates whether this is the selected button or not.
onGraphType: function (container, button, pressed) {
    if (pressed) { ..do stuff.. }
});
```